# Norm of element in Hilbert space: can I take supremum over subspace like this?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X \subset Y$ be Hilbert spaces (with *different norms*), with continuous and dense injections.
We have
$$\lVert y \rVert_Y = \sup_{v \in Y, \lVert v \rVert_Y \leq 1} |(y,v)_Y|$$
Is it true that
$$\lVert y \rVert_Y = \sup_{x \in X, \lVert x \rVert_X \leq 1} |(y,x)_Y|$$
I know I can take the supremum over $X$ instead but can I take the "norm less than 1" condition with the $X$ norm too? Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question properly but what if $y\in X^\perp$.

Comment: @tom maybe my edit will make that situation impossible?

Comment: *Hilbert* spaces with *dense* embedding? Isn't it the case then that it must be the identity?

Comment: @Berci How can that be? Consider $X = H^1$ and $Y = L^2$. They are not equal spaces but satisfy the conditions in my post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample:

- $Y=\ell^2$, square summable sequences $(y_n:n\ge 1)$ with the norm $\sqrt{\sum |y_n|^2}$
- $X=\ell^2_w$, weighted $\ell^2$ space with the norm $\sqrt{\sum n|x_n|^2}$

Clearly, $X$ is a dense subset of $Y$, since it contains all finite sequences.

Given $y\in Y$ and $x\in X$ with $\|x\|_X\le 1$, use Hölder's inequality: 
$$ 
  |(y,x)_Y|= \left|\sum n^{1/2}x_n n^{-1/2}\bar y_n\right| \le   \sqrt{\sum n|x_n|^2}\sqrt{\sum n^{-1}|y_n|^2 } \le \sqrt{\sum n^{-1}|y_n|^2 }
 $$
Clearly, the right hand side is strictly less than $\|y\|_Y$.

Considering the equality case of Hölder's inequality, one can conclude that the supremum over all eligible $x$ is indeed equal to $\sqrt{\sum n^{-1}|y_n|^2 }$. This is the norm of $y$ in $X^*$, the dual space of $X$. We have $X\subset Y\subset X^*$, a [Gelfand triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space).

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is complete, $X$ is closed in $Y$. Since $X$ is also dense, $X$ is in fact equal to $Y$. Thus your question is trivial.

Comment: How do you know that $X$ is complete?

Comment: How can that be? Consider $X = H^1$ and $Y = L^2$. They are not equal spaces but satisfy the conditions in my post?

Comment: What is $H^1{}$?

Comment: $H^1$ is the Sobolev space of $L^2$ functions with weak first order derivatives in $L^2$.

Comment: So when you say $X \subset Y$ are Hilbert spaces, you're allowing $X$ to have a different inner product from $Y$? How perverse.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yes. The norms are different.